# No Ubuntu in GNU GRUB

Tags: command-line, upgrade

I'm Uber sorry for the click bait like title but there is no words to explain my situation right now.
Here is the thing,
20 days ago I was trying update my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16 while doing it my laptop's power run out and process failed, when I replugged the charger I had classic "Ubuntu login loop problem"
I've tried everything in here ; [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)
Nothing helped, I gave up, wasn't using my laptop for 2 week, but today I wanted to fix it. 
However I realised while doing that loop problem Shell was giving "this module version was inactive for this kernel "
Output almost after every bunch of code.
Then I googled for "how to fix Ubuntu kernel", I ended up here ; 
http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/09/how-to-repair-broken-system-after.html?m=1
However, at the first place, I had options like, settings, Ubuntu and things things at boot screen.
I went to recovery mod to apply that broken kernel codes.
Now in the boot menu Ubuntu is gone for like ever. All I got in GNU GRUB
*EFI/Ubuntu/MokManaher.efi
*System setup
*Remix os (nevermind this)
When I go with the EFI thing, it says
"Shim UEFI key management
Continue boot
Enroll key from disk
Enroll hash from disk

Booting in 10 seconds
"
10 seconds after I go back to boot (GNU GRUB) screen.
What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you seem to be in a delicated situation... Try to boot from a Live CD or pen drive. Once running a linux open a terminal and follow:

1. Determine the partition number of your main partition (where your Ubuntu is installed). GParted can help you here (or some command-line based program as `sudo fdisk -l`). I'm going to assume in this answer that it's /dev/sda2, but make sure you use the correct partition number for your system!
2. Mount your partition:

   `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`

   Again: make sure that sda2 is correct! Bind mount some other necessary stuff:

   `for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done`
3. Chroot into your Ubuntu install:

   `sudo chroot /mnt`

   At this point, you're in your install, not the live CD, and running as root.
4. Now try to finish the upgrade:

   `do-release-upgrade`

   `dpkg --reconfigure -a`

If these steps don't solve the problem, at least you can recover your personal stuff and reinstall the system. To do so, simply launch  the file manager and open /mnt/home/username and all your folders will be there (here I'm assuming that when you first formatted Ubuntu, you used /dev/sda2 as your /home mount point too). At this point you can copy them into a pendrive, or open the browser and put them on the cloud.

Comment: well is there a way to recover my downloand and desktop folders to additional hdd ?

Then I can perform a clean install.

Comment: @Blaberus Sure you can, I've just edited the answer to explain how it is done.

Comment: excus me but where I am going to open `window manager`

Comment: @Blaberus sorry I meant file manager. Justy type `nautilus` in the terminal :)